# How to get no of followers of a user on a given day using twitter4j API?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

There is a method user.getFollowersCount(); which gives me no of followers at this point of time. But I want to analyze how no of followers of a user increased over a period of time(like a graph over last one month - day vs no of followers).

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the last day data vs the current one. This will give you how many followers the person has gained. You can do similar calculations with previous dates. As long as you keep the daily data stored you can measure the increase/decrease of followers over time.

Comment: I don't have last day's data. I have to collect all the data now. Is there a mechanism in API to get no of followers on a particular day?